# Pass data to URL and then redirect

Tags: html, forms, post

I am creating and HTML form that submits data to a url on submit. Its working fine and data is passed on, but i am unable to redirect to the url of my choice after data has been passed on.

I want that after submit button it clicked data is passed to the url and user is redirected to www.abc.com

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/821338/gw1ozj/">
<input type="checkbox" name="apple"> Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="mango"> Orange  
<input type="checkbox" name="orange"> Mango

<input type="submit" href="http://www.google.com/"  value="Submit Form" />

</form>
```

Comment: Your form-processing code will determine what happens on form submission, so ideally you should edit your question and add that. Adding an `href` element to your submit button will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write JS function on submit which sends your data by ajax (can be POST method also) to url which you want (that from form action), then redirect manually to www.abc.com by

```
location.href = "www.abc.com";
```

**EDIT**
Solution for sending data to your hooks.zapier.com site, and then redirect it to google.com
You dont need form, just inputs, change button to

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Take me to google.com</button>
```

And body of myFunction()   (wrote using jQuery cause using ajax is much simplier with it)

```
function myFunction(){
    $.post( "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/821338/gw1ozj/",{
        apple: "apple",
        mango: $("input[name='mango']").val() // <- get data from input
    });
    //this can be also in onSucces() in ajax
    location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: Tried that but still the same result. Have a look, or maybe i did not get your point : http://jsfiddle.net/s0y4u61w/3/

Comment: On jsfiddle or Codepen it wont work with an url on the action attribute because is outside of the domain

Comment: @Sali i edited my answer, try it. you didnt understand my first time or i dont understand your problem, then please explain more ;)

Comment: Are you using JQuery, this answer requires that.

Comment: @PoulBak of course not, i can rewrite it to pure JS, but i think it can be easier with it

Comment: sorry, I meant: This answer USES JQuery.

Comment: I tried this and yes data is being passed but occasionally, and appears after alot of delay. While the <form action=" " > method was instant and very reliable. Are u sure there is no want to achieve this via the form action method ?

Comment: insert ```location.href = ...``` to onSuccess function (3rd argument in ```$.post()``` ). i think your site reload can be faster than ajax, thats why you dont get data. And there is no option to implement it by <form action> because it will always send your data to site in 'action', and then will redirect to this url. No way to change it

Comment: @colorgreen There seems to be an issue with the JS code you provided or in the way that i am writing it as no data is being sent over, also no  redirection after click is happening. Could you have a look at the code in this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/83kwazv7/3

Comment: @Sali https://jsfiddle.net/btLhngpj/3/ this code could work but jsfiddle dont allow to make ajax requests on external domains. run it on your local web server. include JS code at the and of body